# Services in Android is not getting Started in BroadCast receiver

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make an android app that must do some database activities like storing phone number and name etc in the SQLite DB . This all Data Base stuff is done as a service. The service must start as soon as the call comes and when the call ends the stored details must be showed to user as soon as the call ends. For this purpose I am using Broad Cast Receiver. I have also provide the following codes which I have used in my app.

MyServices.java

```
public class MyServices extends Service {
TelephonyManager Tel;
MyPhoneStateListener MyListener;
RB_SIGNAL_STRENGTH signalobj = new RB_SIGNAL_STRENGTH();
RB_DatabaseHandler db = new RB_DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    isMyServiceRunning();
    MyListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    Tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Tel.listen(MyListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("Serv","Service Started");

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.close_DB();
    Log.i("Serv","Service Stopped");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
    public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String state=null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) 
    {
        try{


        Intent i = new Intent(context,MyServices.class);

        Log.i("Recv", "In Try");
        context.startService(i);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Recv", "Service not starting");
        }
    }//End if offhook
    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
    {
        Log.i("Recv","CALL ENDED");
        try
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,EndActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);            
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Recv", "Activity not starting");
        }
    }
    }
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity android:name="StartActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="EndActivity" >
    </activity>
            <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service 
        android:name="MyServices" 
        ></service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class name is `MyPhoneReceiver` but in your Manifest you are using `MyReceiver`, these two names must match exactly.

---

**Addition**
I just noticed that you are trying to instantiate your database before the Service has a valid Context. This will probably throw an exception in MyServices:

```
RB_DatabaseHandler db = new RB_DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

You can to declare `db` as a field variable but leave it null:

```
RB_DatabaseHandler db;
```

And inside a method like `onStartCommand()` initialize it:

```
db = new RB_DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

**Lastly,** calling fundamental methods like `onCreate()` out of order usually creates problems, this is not recommended in `onStartCommand()`:

```
super.onCreate();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam. please review my code in this regard and help me out. I am learner in this field. Please its my request. Dropboxhttps://www.dropbox.com/sh/orvbev0qak1ig4q/_DICsnPlDn

Answer (score 1):

because `state` variable is `null`

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
String state=null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    //your code here...
```

Comment: +1 An excellent observation as well ... Hey are you stealing my answer? Tsk, tsk.

Comment: @Sam : actually i want to suggest OP also use full name including package name for declaring service in AndroidManifest

Comment: Hello Sam ρяσѕρєя K for your help , I am able to start service however I am unable to other things which I am supposed to do. I would like to share my code with you guys both, please help me out in this. I am learner in android so please tell me what needs to be done . I have given a text file for your reference.            DropBox link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/orvbev0qak1ig4q/_DICsnPlDn